# How do I get a list of tor relays?

Tags: relays

I see that some websites such as [this one](https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes) have a complete list of all tor relays. How do they dynamically find all of the relays in the tor network?

Comment: Interestingly: https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes is not accessible via tor. https://atlas.torproject.org/ is.

Comment: I can access both. Though through Tor dan.me.uk/tornodes is _much_ slower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely by using the [Onionoo API](https://onionoo.torproject.org/), as used by tools like [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/).