# Does Tor still maintain a list of all relays?

Tags: relays

I know that few years ago ([2015](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-tor-relays) and [2017](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14697/list-of-all-the-entry-nodes)), there was a centralized list of all Tor Relays. Is this still the case? Or is there some decentralization of the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still the same. There are still [9 Directory Authorities](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#search/flag:Authority) (serge is bridge authority) that generate consensuses